# Как подключить виртуальное устройство для отладки приложений в Android Studio для компьютера lenovo g50-45?

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор, genymotion

Процессор AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphic. 2GHz. 4,96 Гб доступной памяти.
При попытке подключить виртуальный девайс через Android Studio возникает ошибка "Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)".
Попытался установить Genymotion, но при запуске виртуального устройства VirtualBox выдаёт "The virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)" (привести детали к сожалению не могу, как и показать лог файл, т.к. удалил Genymotion и VirtualBox).
Удалось подключить Nox Player, но после подключения этого эмулятора вылетает отладка на реальном устройстве, я его снова монтировал, но постоянно переключаться между Nox и смартфоном и лазить в командную строку как-то не очень удобно.
Подскажите, что можно сделать для подключения эмулятора. Не исключаю в качестве помощи ответ на такой вопрос: на указанном компьютере и процессоре отладка на эмуляторе вообще возможна? И ещё, какие принципиальные преимущества имеет отладка на эмуляторе перед реальным устройством? Не связано ли это с тем, что при отладке на смартфоне, последний быстрее изнашивается?

Comment: включить VT-x в настройках BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо включить возможность виртуализации в BIOS, если эта возможность предусмотрена.

Не знаю на счет износа устройства, сомнительно что установка арк файла существенно влияет на срок работы устройства.
Производить отладку с помощью устройства нужно в любом случае, если вы хотите сделать качественное приложение. Эмулятор позволяет Вам запустить приложение на различных устройствах в разных версиях Андроид.

Попробуйте подключить эмулятор BlueStack он менее требователен к ресурсам.

Comment: Подключил виртуализацию в BIOS при помощи автоматического приложения For Lenovo BIOS Updates, во всяком случае в настройках системы отображается, что виртуализация включена. Я думаю, что Nox Player не пошёл бы без виртуализации

Comment: Я Lenovo не пользовался, такой софтины не знаю.
Вот сслыка на инсрукцию как включить виртуализацию 
https://help.qnap.ru/hc/ru/articles/214541045-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-Intel-VTx-AMD-SVM-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5-QNAP-

Comment: Да, я пробовал вручную через BIOS, только там совсем не так, как на вашей предложенной статье. И пункта Virtualization ON/OFF вообще нет

Comment: загуглите есть ли возможность виртуализации у Вашего процессора.

Попрубуйте BlueStack,  у меня тоже были проблемы с железом,  я установил его.  Из минусов нет возможности менять версию android, нельзя менять ориентацию экрана.  Но работает он объективно быстрее Дженимоушена.

Comment: спасибо большое) я попробую